# Ruby on Rails generating controller with existing folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

I'm really new at this and I don't want to mess up my current application. I'm currently working on HTML/CSS stuff but I have a little understanding as to how to get things working.

I created a new controller by just doing

```
rails generate controller sign_up
```

I've created a index file (`index.html.erb`) inside sign_up folder from rails that automatically generated. Now I wanted to add more files, can I just add more files by typing in

```
rails generate controller sign_up send_page more_page other_pages
```

Will `send_page`, `more_page`, `other_pages` be automatically combined into the existing `sign_up` folder? Is this the correct way of adding pages if I want rails to add other files automatically? I just want it to ruin what I have so far so I don't want to try it for myself because I'm still really new to this,

Thanks!

Comment: just create a new file under the views folder. no need to use the generator :)

Comment: it doesn't need to create the necessary tools to output it in the web browser?

Comment: when you run rails g controller, you're just creating the controller and the folder and any view file that you passed as a parameter.  so if you want to add a new action, which will most probably need a matching view, you can just edit the controller and add the action there and create a new file in the view :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question :

New files will be added to the existing folder but existing files will not be merged, you'll have to resolve the conflict by choosing between old and new files.

It seems to me you're trying to use generators for every action you need in your app :

Scaffolding is great to have a sample structure, but as soon as you start building your controller for real you need to move away from it : extend the controllers, models and views by hand. It's the only way you'll start to really understand how things are working.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the generator again, it's going to complain about conflicts with existing files.  Then you'll have to choose to overwrite (losing your existing changes to e.g. the controller), or not (in which case you won't get the new auto-generated methods, etc.).

You can just create a new controller action and a new view for each additional page you want to add (and a unit test, of course!).  If you're using non-standard/non-restful action names, you'll also have to edit `config/routes.rb` to route them.

Looking at the names in your example, and your reference to "pages", I suspect what you really may want to do is create separate controllers for `send_page` and `more_page`.  If that's the case, you'd run the generator separately for each new controller.